# different date format to one date format in table

Tags: oracle, date

I have two DATE column in table oracle database(12c).sysdate format is:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;
SYSDATE
---------
25-NOV-17

SQ>desc test_table
id                         NUMBER(10)
LAST_CREATED_DATE          DATE
IS_CREATED_DATE            DATE
```

where LAST_CREATED_DATE has different format to IS_CREATED_DATE(sysdate).
because LAST_CREATED_DATE is fixed and i'm reading from file(date format:20100330) where as IS_CREATED_DATE am inserting as sysdate(current date).

```
insert into test_table (id,LAST_CREATED_DATE,IS_CREATED_DATE) values (123,20100930,sysdate);
```

but with this insert statement am facing errors.
I tried **ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyymmdd';**.This works fine in current session,but looking for by which i can change ORACLE database date format to yyyymmdd(linux).

Comment: You preset NLS_DATE_FORMAT also by Environment variable or in your registry

Answer (score 2):

You should change your statement like this:

```
insert into test_table (id,LAST_CREATED_DATE,IS_CREATED_DATE) 
values (123,to_date('20100930','yyyymmdd'),sysdate);
```

Comment: it works fine in normal case but I'm storing LAST_CREATED_DATE into an array and trying to insert using an plsql package.There it is failing.

Comment: Please explain in which way you want to insert your array of LAST_CREATED_DATE?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to accomplish this task :

1)

```
SQL>conn myschema/mypwd
SQL>insert into test_table values(123,to_date('20100930','yyyymmdd'),sysdate);
```

2) as you mentioned

```
SQL>alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyymmdd';
SQL>insert into test_table values(123,'20100930',sysdate); -- notice that 20100930 is quoted
```

3) globally(along with the db, needs restart, maybe dangerous on a production system in coordination with existing applications' date format model)

```
SQL>conn / as sysdba
SQL>alter system set nls_date_format = 'yyyymmdd' scope=spfile;
SQL>shutdown immediate;
SQL>startup;
SQL>conn myschema/mypwd
SQL>insert into test_table values(123,'20100930',sysdate); -- from now on, you don't need to alter your date parameter for every session
```